# Rails performing actions (vote) on post's index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails app has Designs (posts), which have comments, which those comments can be liked (voted on).

To show those comments on the Design show page, my DesignsController looks like:

```
def show
  @comments = @design.comments
end
```

Now, in the view, I have an each block to list each of the comments but this has been put into a partial for the ajax.

The partial with the each block looks something like this (i will simplify)

```
<% @design.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.body %>
   <p class="comment_vote">
     <%= render("comments/like_button") %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the like_button partial:

```
<% if current_user.voted_on?(@comment) %>
  <%= link_to polymorphic_path([@targetable, @comment.design, @comment], action: :unlike), :method => :post, :class => ("liked" if current_user.voted_on?(@comment)), :remote => true do %>
    Unlike
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to polymorphic_path([@targetable, @comment.design, @comment], action: :like), :method => :post, :remote => true do %>
    Like
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, the like button is also in another partial which requires me to use a global variables (@comment, instead of comment).

Without ajax, I was able to have user's like each individual comment and it was just refreshing the page, because the user was liking the "local variable" `comment`. Now that I'm using ajax, in my like.js.coffee file I have to use a global variable, `@comment` which hasn't been defined in my controller. So what's happening is the ajax works fine and every comment gets liked, instead of just the specific one the user is liking. Can anyone shed some light to this issue and help me solve it?? i'd much rather be using ajax then page-refreshes.

thanks, as always

**EDIT**
the answer from @muistooshort is still liking all of the comments at once

Comment: What is in your `like_button` partial? Can you post the contents?

Comment: I edited my post to include the `like_button`

Answer (score 3):

I'd send the comment in through `:locals`:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/like_button', :locals => { :comment => comment } %>
```

Then you can refer to `comment` in your partial.

You'll also have to do something with `@targetable` but I have no idea what that is or where it is supposed to come from (and this is a good enough reason IMO to be using `targetable` rather than `@targetable`).

Comment: can't you simply write? render "comments/like_button", comment: comment

Comment: @TheRusskiy: Perhaps but I prefer to be explicit so that I don't have to work that hard to see what's going on or worry about conflicts between options and my variable names. Shorter isn't necessarily better.

Comment: kind of resonates with your nickname :-)

Comment: @muistooshort, please check my edit, because I'm still getting an error from that.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `$(".comment_vote").html("<%= ... comment: @comment %>");` in your `.js.coffee`?

Comment: Yea the ajax works but it's still liking all of the comments at once, instead of each one individually

Comment: What do you mean "liking them all at once"? Is the AJAX doing the wrong thing? The JavaScript? The controller?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Without the ajax, the likes were liking individual comments. For some reason, now when I like one of the comments, all of the comments are getting liked. I am going to look some more to find the problem. You have helped a lot so thank you very much! Cheers!